# pic random drawcircle function on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, draw

I created 3 functions where a circle become drawed on the canvas. Now I want that one of the 3 functions become executed random in the draw() function. How can I realize that?

```
    function drawcircle1()
      {
      var radius = x * 5;
        ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.arc(ballx * 100, canvasHeight / 2, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
          ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
          ctx.fill(); 
      }
    function drawcircle2()
      {
      var radius = x * 5;
        ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.arc(ballx * 100, canvasHeight / 2, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
          ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
          ctx.fill(); 
      }
      function drawcircle3()
      {
      var radius = x * 5;
        ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.arc(ballx * 100, canvasHeight / 2, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
          ctx.fillStyle = 'orange';
          ctx.fill(); 
      }
    function draw() {   

   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

      // here should the draw function pic random one of the 3 drawcircle functions


  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

store the functions in an array and generate a random index:

```
function drawRandom(drawFunctions){
    //generate a random index
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * drawFunctions.length);

    //call the function
    drawFunctions[randomIndex]();
}

//store all functions in an array and call drawRandom
drawRandom([drawcircle1, drawcircle2, drawcircle3]);
```

[I have added a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g76jhb70/). It demonstrates the idea of the implementation

---

you should also consider a small refactoring, since all functions do the same except the color:

```
 function drawColoredCircle(color)
      {
      var radius = x * 5;
        ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.arc(ballx * 100, canvasHeight / 2, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
          ctx.fillStyle = color;
          ctx.fill(); 
      }
 function drawcircle1(){ drawColoredCircle('yellow'); }
 function drawcircle2(){ drawColoredCircle('blue'); }
 function drawcircle3(){ drawColoredCircle('orange'); }
```

which leads to another possible solution for random drawing:

```
function drawRandomColor(colors){
    //generate a random index
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    var randomColor = colors[randomIndex];
    //call the function
    drawColoredCircle(randomColor);
}

drawRandomColor(["yellow", "blue", "orange"]);
```

Comment: With this all three circles become drawed on the canvas :(

Comment: I have added a jsfiddle which is demonstrating the code i have just posted. just replace the "dummyFunctions" with your drawcircle methods

Answer (score 1):

```
var randomNum = Math.random();
if(randomNum < .333) drawcircle1();
else if(randomNum < .666) drawcircle2();
else drawcircle3();
```